# How to import external css file in nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webpack-loader, css-import

I am working on react based nextjs app. Some npm packages are using external css import. 
I am getting error like

```
Module parse failed, you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

How can I support css import from external packages in my nextjs app. I have checked somewhere by making change in next.config.js, it works. But I am unable to find the proper one.It would be great if someone can help me around this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

##### For Global CSS

To add global css, inside the file `pages/_app.js` use `import '../styles.css'` or to import from `node_modules`, use something similar to `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'`

##### For Component Level CSS

> Next.js supports CSS Modules using the `[name].module.css` file naming convention.
> CSS Modules locally scope CSS by automatically creating a unique class name. This allows you to use the same CSS class name in different files without worrying about collisions.

If you have a component called `Button` inside `Button.js`, create a file called `Button.module.css` for the css file. Then you can import it to the `Button` component by `import styles from './Button.module.css'`

[Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)

#### Old Answer

You can add the css file in head of nextjs.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
```

and in the render method, inside the return add a head tag similar to ordinary HTML, the head tag should be inside a div.

```
<div>
    <Head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <link href="/static/master.css" rel="stylesheet" key="test"/>
    </Head>
</div>
```

also the css should be in static folder. Add a key to the link tag to reuse the css in multiple pages. If the key is same across pages, then the next server won't reload the css, but instead will reuse the css file.

This way there is no need for any css packages either.

Comment: I have created the assets directory at root and its not working but somehow after checking this comment I renamed the directory to static and its working fine now.

Comment: By far the simplest answer to this very simple question but difficult to fathom question. Thanks±

Comment: how about a css file hosted on a cdn somewhere. how do i include it?

Answer (score 12):

You first need to create a `next.config.js` file in root directory

Install next-css

```
npm i @zeit/next-css
```

in next.config.js

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()
```

Restart app

**USAGE**

```
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'
```

No need for dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: This is the proper solution, everything else is a hack.

Comment: Note that since version 9.2 Next.js has built-in support for CSS. You should no longer use `@zeit/next-css` (it's also been deprecated).

Answer (score 1):

you can simply move your css file into public folder /public/{name}.css like this

and import css file inside src/pages/_document.js file

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

...
<Head>
   <link href="/{name}.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</Head>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. import your external css file into the component. For example, [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) requires you to add their stylesheet in order to make its styles work. You can import their stylesheets using

   ```
   import rsStyles from 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'
   ```
2. Inject style in your component using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` at `render` method

   ```
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: rsStyles }} />
         // rest of your component code 
         // where you can use the injected styles
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

inside _app.js you can do the following:

```
if (someCondition){
import('../styles/rtl.css');
}
```

Comment: does this code run on the client and/or on the server? if server, does it run for every request?

Answer (score 0):

in your _app.js file

put all your js scripts in the  tag in return block
like this

```
export default function App(props) {

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://unpkg.com/react-quill@1.3.3/dist/quill.snow.css"
        />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Font-Awesome.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slick.min.js"></script>
      </Head>
      <AuthProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```